# Time Machine backup to FTP server

Tags: macos, ftp

How can I get a Mac computer using Time Machine to back up to a server using FTP?

I have not tried anything yet and everything I've search for is about 6 years old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Time Machine officially only supports the AFP protocol, version 3.3 or later (the specific requirements list is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/TimeMachineNetworkInterfaceSpecification/TimeMachineRequirements/TimeMachineRequirements.html)). You can fake it over some other file sharing protocols (e.g. SMB), but there's a high incidence of corrupted backup sets. FTP is too primitive to even fake it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use arqbackup.com as a Time Machine Alternative; that will backup your files to external storages such as FTP-Server, Google-Cloud, etc.